# Anticipated water pressure drop in the water softener circuit, please advise

Tags: water-pressure, water-softener, water-quality

**My existing water softener system consists of the following**:

Pressure tank -> Culligan Whole house filter (R50) -> Iron Filter -> Softener -> main line to the house

There is an RO after the softener for drinking water.

I am in the process of getting the circuit upgraded to the following - primarily to get all the iron out of the water and foul smells.

Well -> Pressure Tank 20G -> Spin down filter -> Chlorine Injection -> 1” Static Inline Mixer (16 GPM) -> 48 Gal Contact Retention Tank -> Spin down filter -> Sediment Backwash Filter 12x52 2.0CF -> Pro-Ox Iron Filter 12x52 5900BT Air -> Spin down filter -> Carbon Backwash Filter 12x52 2.0CF -> Spin Down Filter -> Softener -> Culligan Whole House Filter (R50) ->  Pressure Tank 20G -> Grudfos SCALA2 230V Booster Pump -> Main line to the house.

I am in the middle of setting up the circuit for the above connections and I realized that - if there is a pressure drop in-between the tanks, it would be difficult to remedy once the system is live. Hence I wanted to reach out to the experts to get some suggestions about their opinion on the expected water pressure drop in a system like this.

**My questions is:**

1. Should I put a pressure tank 20G half way through the circuit (between the Iron filter and the carbon filter) to ensure that there is adequate pressure through out the circuit - until the water gets to the booster pump?

Thanks in advance for your valuable recommendations / comments / suggestions.

Comment: This is 3 separate questions related to each other only by the fact that they're involved in your water supply system. Each of them is mostly unrelated to the other, and they should be asked as 3 separate questions here. Please [edit] this down to just one of the questions, then ask the other 2 each in their own question. You can post links in them to help others find the background info so you don't have to copy/paste everything in 3 places.

Comment: Also, what to do the water test results have to do with anything?